# Jsplumb endpoint paint style makes endpoint disappear

Tags: jquery, jsplumb

I am working on a project with jsplumb and I am creating an endpoint. The endpoint creation works fine, until I try and set a paint style to change the endpoint colour, and instead the endpoint disappears.

Below is how I am creating the endpoint

```
jspInstance.addEndpoint(widget,
                {anchor: "Right", isSource: true, isTarget: false,
                    paintStyle: {
                        strokeStyle: "#ff3520",
                        lineWidth:3
                    },
                    overlays: [[
                    "Label", {
                        "label": "No Selection Route",
                        "location": [0.5, 1.4],
                        labelStyle: {
                            color: "black"
                        }
                    }
                    ]]
                });
```

If I remove the paintStyle object the endpoint appears fine, but disappears with the painStyle. I've tried `strokeStyle` and `fillStyle` but no joy.

Comment: Which version are you using? According to the Changelog (https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/doc/changelog.html) there was an overhaul of the `paintStyle` object in v2.2.0 that included renaming all the supported property names. The new property names are documented here: https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/doc/paint-styles.html

Comment: Yep that was it, I was using the latest version, but I guess the Google search I did took me to the old documentation.